# Change iframe's window's parent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Change iframe's window's parent

Is it possible to change the contentWindow.parent of an iframe.  What I want to do is:

```
window.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.parent = window.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.window
```

The above works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera but not IE.

The reason for doing this my iframe (let's call it TOP) itself has iframes in it (let's call them SUBWINDOWS), and both of them have Javascript that calls "parent.document.getElementById" and such.  When you are in a top level window then parent.document.getElementId is the same as document.getElementById because for a top level window parent == window.  For the iframe SUBWINDOWS parent.document refers to the the document of the top level window.  Seems a bit sloppy, but it works, relying on the fact that parent == window for a top level window.

But now that top level window TOP is now an iframe in a bigger page (let's call it BIG).  The Javascript in TOP that does parent.document.getElementById is now referring to BIG's document, whereas before it was referring to TOP's document.

So one quick and easy fix is to change the iframe's parent to point to itself.  And this indeed works for Firefox, Chrome, Opera.

Any ideas for how to get it to work for IE?

--

My test code is:

```
test.html:

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>Text outside iframe</p>
<iframe id="myframe" src="test_more.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

test_more.html:

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>Text inside iframe</p>
<input type="button" value="window/parent" onclick="alert('window.location.href = ' + window.location.href + '\nparent.location.href = ' + parent.location.href);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Put these files on a web server to avoid the same origin policy error and go to the URL like localhost:6144/test/test.html.

Comment: IF IE doesn”t want to play ball, then he doesn’t want to play ball. (And having that property be read-only makes sense, a script should not _have_ to mess with it in the first place.) What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve here? If you want to access the top most window instance in any case, then you could simply switch `parent` for `top`.

Comment: The problem I want to solve is to NOT have the Javascript in the iframe TOP access its parent.  But Javascript in the iframe SUBWINDOWS should use parent, and if TOP is not enclosed in an iframe then it can continue to use "parent." but it doesn't matter if it does or does not.  From the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it looks like parent is read only because they use the term "Retrieves" whereas for other properties like name they use "Sets or retrieves".  I wonder if this is standards compliant.

Comment: _“The problem I want to solve is …”_ – not any more clear to me now than it was before. Can you give a precise example of what exactly goes wrong in what situation, and what you would want to happen instead? // As for “specification”, most of the stuff surrounding the `window` object is not part of ECMAScript, but only of having a “host object” in the JS implementation in a browser environment, and as such it is less rigorously specified – most of it is rather just “historically grown”.